# JQGrid treegrid not expanding as expected

Tags: jqgrid

I can't quite get my JQGrid treegrid to expand correctly. Its is a hierarchical adjacency grid.

When I expand the root node, the subnodes expand and indent correctly but they arent placed directly under the node.

Is there something wrong with my json data? Id like to have nodes that are expandable appear first and leaf nodes appear below them.

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/3194/ (I've renamed all nodes bob, but the weird expanding behaviour can still be seen)

```
$(function () {

    var mydata = [{"id":"5a1a9743-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"9042ded8-09ee-46f9-beac-8746ed1cdd17","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"29846baa-ede0-4582-b9ed-39bcc486f2c2","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"39cc2783-811f-4885-9af6-d35b1a1385a2","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"3061ce07-bff6-4d9a-a84a-a8a7d47ebd7a","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"d1f870ed-bca6-4cc8-8b96-b19fa251c2f8","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","name":"bob","level":0,"parent":null,"isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"c80ca2d1-8210-4c11-8c6d-005c97fce9cb","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"d9dadce8-a9ce-4343-a8a0-b80844aa36ad","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"b3bc918c-4fa6-4470-afdd-d98e3586d434","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":false,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"466d78df-6f39-43ff-abfd-58e7bf91f8c8","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},{"id":"be4c23b9-41a2-482f-a37a-33379ea03344","name":"bob","level":1,"parent":"5a1a9742-3e0f-11d3-941f-006008032006","isLeaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true}];                


    $("#treegrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "jsonstring",
        datastr: mydata,
    colNames: ["id", "partners"],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true, key: true },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 500, sortable: false, classes: 'pointer' },                       
    ],
    height: 'auto',
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 10000,
    sortname: 'name',
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',           
    ExpandColumn: 'name',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    }
});        

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just small misunderstanding how jqGrid builds TreeGrid. You have to provide **sorted** data as the input. *jqGrid just place all the rows in exact the order like one have in input* to the grid. The collapsed rows will be just *hidden*. If the user expand the node jqGrid shows all rows which have the expanding node as the parent.

So to fix the problem you have to resort the input data so that all direct children should follow the parent. Probably you need additionally include first nodes which are not leafs (having `isLeaf: false`) and then the children which are leafs (having `isLeaf: true`). Additionally you should sort all nodes by `sortname` option (by `"name"` column in your case).

By the way you can remove `id` column from `colModel`. jqGrid uses `id` property of input data by default as input for rowid (the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements of the grid).

See update demo http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/3204/

Comment: ah thanks Oleg, I thought that might be the issue. I'll try sort the data server side before returning it.

Comment: sorting the data is harder than I thought...I might need to ask another question to figure it out! I've tried a bunch of combinations of ordering with no luck. `list.OrderBy(x => x.parent).ThenBy(x => x.level).ThenBy(x => x.isLeaf);`

Comment: @woggles: You are welcome! I agree that sorting of the TreeGrid could be not so simple like it looks like at the first look. It's important how the data are native saved in the database. If the number of items is not large then you can use *any* sort method which could be not optimal.

Comment: I've asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404603/c-sharp-sorting-data-from-an-adjacency-tree to see if I can get further insight!

Comment: @woggles: I am busy now, but if you will not get the answer in the next time I will try to help you later.

Answer (score 0):

Currently jqGrid can work only with data returned from server.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid#options

Create a simple web page that returns your JSON.

Comment: thanks, I am returning data from the server...I just made it local version with simplified data so that I could show make a sample on jsfiddle. Here is a working sample courtesy of Oleg: http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree8.htm