# c# sorting data from an adjacency tree

Tags: c#, recursion, jqgrid, tree

I have a bunch of data that will be represented as a tree. The control that I'm using requires the data to be ordered correctly.

This is the structure of each node:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public Guid? parent { get; set; }
    public bool isLeaf { get; set; }    
}
```

I need a way to sort the data so that I have a list of TreeNodes with the root first, followed by its children and so on. In other words all direct children need to follow the parent in the list.

I would also like subnodes and leaf nodes to be sorted by name. (`>` = expandable, `o` = leaf)

```
root >
  level1a >         
  level1b >
     level2d >
     level2a o
  level1a o
  level1b o
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm assuming I'll need some recursive function and not wont be able to sort it using a combination of order by statements (something like `list.OrderBy(x => x.parent).ThenBy(x => x.level).ThenBy(x => x.isLeaf);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that doing this with a single LINQ expression is not straightforward. This recursive approach should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode> TreeOrder(
    IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes)
{
    //Find the root node
    var root = nodes.Single(node => node.parent == null);

    //Build an inverse lookup from parent id to children ids
    var childrenLookup = nodes
        .Where(node => node.parent != null)
        .ToLookup(node => node.parent.Value);

    return TreeOrder(root, childrenLookup);
}

IEnumerable<TreeNode> TreeOrder(
    TreeNode root,
    ILookup<Guid, TreeNode> childrenLookup)
{
    yield return root;

    if (!childrenLookup.Contains(root.id))
        yield break;

    foreach (var child in childrenLookup[root.id])
        foreach (var node in TreeOrder(child, childrenLookup))
            yield return node;
}
```

Comment: You can compare the input data with directories and the files. `isLeaf` property means: "is the file?". The order should corresponds **expanding order of directors tree sorted by name**. Fist in the list should be "A". The last in the list should be "files" (items having `isLeaf === true`) of "A". If all items are "directories" then the correct order should be "ABDECFG". If one directory has both subdirectories *and* files then one should list first subdirectories and then the files.

Comment: @Timothy: what Oleg said :) ABDECFG

Comment: @Timothy, won't compile: `foreach (var node in TreeOrder(childrenLookup[root.id])` no overload for TreeOrder takes 1 argument. I also changed `.Where(node.parent.HasValue)` to `.Where(node  => node.parent.HasValue)`

Comment: @Timothy, still not quite there...`childrenLookup[root.id]` returns an IEnumerable...should I just take `childrenLookup[root.id].First()`? Impressive browser code :)

Comment: `childrenLookup[root.id]` returns an `IEnumerable<TreeNode>`. That's why it's being used an as `IEnumerable<TreeNode>` in the outer `foreach` loop. Maybe you're looking at the previous version before I edited it, where I still had the error?

Comment: @timothy yep, I was looking at an old version! Works like a charm...Only thing that I need to add is having the leaf nodes below the expandable nodes and sorting alphabetically on top of that. Thanks